# Is there tab completion for Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, anaconda

I wanted to have tab completion in my Anaconda Prompt on Windows 10.

When searching for a solution, I discovered a lot of linux-related information.
Even the [official manual](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/enable-tab-completion.html) mentions only Bash and zsh.

To be sure that it doesn't work for Windows 10, I've done what was told:
1. `conda install argcomplete`
2. `eval "$(register-python-argcomplete conda)"` in my `.bashrc` file that is located in the user's root folder.
3. Relaunched Anaconda Prompt.
4. The tab completion didn't work.

Therefore, I have the following question,
Is there tab completion for Anaconda on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for this and from what I could read it is not available.
I have made a feature request: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9666
My imagination tells me one could hack something together using dynamic power-shell auto-complete within a power-shell wrapper for `conda activate` which calls `conda env list` to update the auto-complete list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627601/powershell-dynamic-tab-completion
Unfortunately, doing so is currently beyond me...